# When users given full control, existing users are overwritten - why? And how to remove access for inherited groups? C#

Tags: c#, file, permissions, addition

I have a txt file with a list of users in it. I want these users to be granted full access to a file/directory, then remove ALL other permissions from the file. This is the code I am using to give the list of users full control:

```
    var readerAdminUsers = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(adminFile));
    string adminUser = string.Empty;
    var allAdminUsers = new List<String>();
    FileSystemAccessRule fsar;
    FileSecurity fileSec = new FileSecurity();

    while (!readerAdminUsers.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = readerAdminUsers.ReadLine();
        adminUser = line;
        allAdminUsers.Add(adminUser);

        fsar = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUser, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        fileSec.AddAccessRule(fsar);
        numOfAdmins++;
    }

    File.SetAccessControl(filePath, fileSec);
```

However, once the access control has been set, any other users that I had added to the file (that are not in the admin list) have been removed! But the inherited groups (such as the administrator and system groups) do still have permissions. What is causing this to remove users at this point?

I'm then having the problem that when I try to remove those inherited groups they are still there and I can't figure out how to remove them. This is the code for that part:

```
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
    if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    {
        var security = Directory.GetAccessControl(filePath);
        arc = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    }
    else
    {
        var security = File.GetAccessControl(filePath);
        arc = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    }

    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in arc)
    {
        string username = rule.IdentityReference.Value;               
        if (!allAdminUsers.Contains(username))
        {
            fileSec.RemoveAccessRule(rule);
            File.SetAccessControl(filePath, fileSec);        
        }
    }
```

I start with a file that has for example: 
- 3 users that I added 
- and the inherited system and administrators groups
 
At the end what I want is to have: 
- no users (unless they are one of the admins specified in the txt file)
- none of the user groups
- and the admins from the file with full control 
What I am getting is: 
- the 3 users are gone
- the inherited groups is still there 
- and the admin users have full control

Please note that adding deny access is not what I'm looking for, I need them fully removed.

Please help me fix this!
Many thanks :)